# Making a link that comes with a script unclickable

Tags: css, hyperlink

I want to put an [online counter](http://freehostedscripts.net/onlinecounter/) on my (tumblr) blog.

I get a script as a result.

I know where and how to add that code, but I'm wondering how to make this link/script unclickable? Otherwise you can click on it and view a map of all the people that are currently online and I find that rather creepy.

How can I make this unclickable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy CSS way: add a css-class to the document.write-span-tag part of the code which is inserted to your document via the code snippet you included:

```
<span id='o_"+fhs_id+"'></span>
```

change to

```
<span class='unclickable' id='o_"+fhs_id+"'></span>
```

and add a CSS rule to where ever you have your CSS like this:

```
.unclickable {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

(works in most browsers, also internet explorer 10 and newer.
for older browsers you'll probably need a javascript solution)

javascript solution:

add onClick='return false' to the same snippet part:

```
<span id='o_"+fhs_id+"' onClick='return false'></span>
```

Comment: is there some kind of guideline? i am new to this

Comment: Pls separate your answer into paragraphs and use inline code block like `onclick='return false'`. Guideline goes [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18614/style-guide-for-questions-and-answers)

Answer (score 1):

```
<a class="btn" href="http://freehostedscripts.net/oc.php?id=SUQ5MDAwMDAwMXxmcmVlaG9zdGVkc2NyaXB0cy5uZXR8MA==" title="319 Online [FHS]" target="_blank">319 Online Users</a>
```

so that's what you have you can do

```
<a class="btn" onclick="return false"...
```

Comment: you should also do <a class="btn" onclick="return false" cursor="default" style="text-decoration: none;" ...